# cosmos gremline cross container mapping

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinnet

Cosmos DB Gremlins two graph ( container ) - graph1 & graph 2 .

graph1- - person(node )
graph2- - city(node )

can we make edge between person and city where they are located different container ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can we make edge between person and city where they are located different container ?

No, AFAIK it is not possible. You can only connect two nodes in the same container.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav . I tried lot but did not succeed to connect two node b/w different container . Did you find any Cosmos db doc where its mentioned that its not possible for our documents ?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: thanks . even I tried to find some doc to show management but not finding any thanks for respond

Comment: If you're on Twitter, you can tag @azurecosmosdb and ask them the same.

Comment: As stated in the answer, it is no possible to connect and edge and node in two different containers. Tweeting at the Cosmos Twitter handle will not yield any better answers given that I'm the one monitoring it. A good source of documentation for Gremlin that you may want to look at is here, https://tinkerpop.apache.org/gremlin.html